# How can I put a flexible width div into a fixed width container?

Tags: css

What I want to do is to slide the content of the first div so that the only content shown would be what is not hidden by the outer div.

I am trying this, but doesn't work

```
#contenedorProductos {
margin-left: 50px;
float: center;
position: absolute;
width: 490px;
text-align: center;
z-index:1;
}

#contenedorProductos #contenidoProductos {
overflow: auto;
position: absolute;
width: auto;
}
```

My english skills don't let me explain better, hope this to be understood... Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `overflow: hidden;` on the outer div, and **remove** `position: absolute;` from the inner div (and possibly from the outer div - margin and float has no effect when using absolute position):

```
#contenedorProductos {

    margin-left: 50px;
    float: center;
    width: 490px;
    text-align: center;
    z-index:1;
    overflow: hidden;

}

#contenedorProductos #contenidoProductos {

    width: auto;

}
```